# php random number in Session, how to compare?

Tags: php, security, session

EDIT: As explained below by Cheery and edited by me for conciseness :

Session values are only for the given session id only if the session id is replaced by another, existing session - this is where security steps are required if you are concerned about stealing of the session id value. Sessions are on the server. You can only spoof the session id, but it should be the id of the existing session, otherwise $_SESSION will be empty.

---

I not finding anything useful related to my question:

I'm trying to secure my custom backoffice and have the following code after verifying the password:

```
if ($hasher->CheckPassword($password_safe, $retrieved_password)) {
    //Initiate the session
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = md5(microtime(true));
    $_SESSION["ip"] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    header('Location: main.php');
} else {
    //LOGIN ATTEMPT FAILED
}
unset($hasher);
}
```

Since this is only for my own use I'm not concerned with the problems associated with the Ip check part nor with storing the user ID.

What Im not figuring out how to do is what to compare

```
$_SESSION["user_id"]
```

to on the private pages.

I realize that I need that same value stored somewhere else, is putting it to the db the only way?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you randomizing your user IDs, and what are you expecting to happen? I really have no clue what you intend to achieve.

Comment: Think about it, there is only one thing that _could_ make sense: Have the client pass that value back with the next request (via cookie, GET or POST), so that you can compare that value you get passed to the one you have stored in your session. And now think about it some more – there already _is_ such a “secret” random value, the session id. So that approach of trying to “increase security” is rather pointless (because if someone was able to steal the session id, they would most likely be able to steal that second secret code as well).

Comment: user_id really is a a bad name that I forgot to edit before making it be a random number. I want to avoid possible session fixation/hijack attacks.

Comment: But is not the session id available in the clear on the browser to the user? I might be confusing it with the random string associated with the cookie. Also, right now I was going to write it to the DB along with an expiration date and compare that.

Comment: `But is not the session id available available in the clear on the browser to the user?` yes, but how does it affect the `user_id`? Regenerate session id with every request, check IP address, destroy session cookie when browser is closed.

Comment: To prevent session hyjacking use HTTPS....

Comment: Would a $_SESSION["logged"] = yes be as secure as what im trying to do? Perhaps In not making my logic clear or Im just plain wrong. Thank you all for the comments.

Comment: `be as secure as what im trying to do` sessions are stored on server and user does not have direct access to it, only to the session id. If no other others of the same server can modify your session, it is ok. Just perform normal security checks.

Comment: I think that Im making some wrong assumptions. On on a next page when I call  $_SESSION["logged"] is this value associated with the session id? I mean does it belong to that unique session id?

Comment: @Marvin yes, the session values are only for the given session id, they are not shared between users (only if session id is replaced by another, existing session - this is where security steps are required if you are concerning about stealing of the session id value)

Comment: So I could not in some way just send a crafted session to one of my pages with the simple value of $_SESSION["logged"] = yes ? I believe it could not be done since that particular session would not be registered in the server.

Comment: @Marvin you cannot send session to the server, it is stored on server. You can only spoof the session id, but it should be the id of the existing session, otherwise `$_SESSION` will be empty. Check IP, regenerate session id, use secure connection, set session cookie lifetime until browser is closed, destroy session by timeout on absence of user's activity - typical security measures.

Comment: How many users are in the db has nothing to do with whether or not you check for session hijacking. "Oh, I only have one users; there's no way anyone could hijack his session."  Really???

Comment: @developerwjk What I meant was that I was not concerned with the troubles often associated with checking the IP (proxies, etc) and in distinguishing between which user is logged in. That was not clear and I will edit as to not mislead anyone.

Comment: I'm referring to where you say "I'm not concerned with the Ip check part": you put the IP and user-agent in the session (at time of login) and check the request IP and user-agent against it again on next request to prevent session hijacking.  SSL will help on that too, but SSL alone won't cut it.  You need this too.

Comment: What you're missing is you should save to the session at time of successful login, not just when a user hits the page.

Comment: For clarity I will edit the code above so it becomes more clear when I am setting those values.

Comment: Still don't get why your user_id is not a userid but an md5'd unix timestamp.

Comment: A mistake in naming since I started by having it hold the user_id but as pointed in the above comments it was a mistake. I don't know if I should edit that detail or just delete the whole question...

Answer (score 0):

You can save it with javascript localstorage and call it when you need it.

**Example**

```
<script>
window.localStorage.setItem("session_id","37363732");    
</script>
```

And in php you call this

```
<?php
$session_id = "<script>
              var sess_id = window.localStorage.getItem("session_id");
              document.write(sess_id);
              </script>";
?>
```

OR this

```
<?php
$session_id = "<script>
              document.write(localStorage.session_id);
              </script>";
?>
```

document.write(localStorage.save);